# relation between tuple values in a list according to their position

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

Consider a list containing tuples like:

```
tuplelist = [('a','b', 'c', 'd'), (6, 3, 9, 11), (0, 4, 5, 6)]
```

How can i match corresponding tuple positions.For ex for `'d'`:

```
(d, 'has_val', 11)
(d, 'has_val', 6)
```

i have tried the following:

```
str = 'has_val'
for i in tuplelist:
    rel = (i[3],str,i[3])
```

but this doesn't give me the desired output

Comment: Do you want to do this for all of your values in the first and second tuples?

Comment: no, i just want to relate  'd' which is at pos 4 in 1st tuple to pos 4 in second and third tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, Don't name your variable as `str` as it shadows the builtin function.

```
tuplelist = [('a','b', 'c', 'd'), (6, 3, 9, 11), (0, 4, 5, 6)]
s = 'has_val'
```

Now coming to your issue, It's aesthetic to have the first row out as a header row. Also note that, I've used the `index` function to find the index instead of directly hard coding `3`. This is helpful if there is a change in the number of columns.

```
header_row = tuplelist[0]
column_name = 'd'
column_index = header_row.index(column_name)
```

Now for the logic, Loop from the second element using slices.

```
for i in tuplelist[1:]:
    print(column_name,s,i[column_index])
```

This would give you the desired output.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like `zip` is your friend:

```
>>> zip(*tuplelist)
[('a', 6, 0), ('b', 3, 4), ('c', 9, 5), ('d', 11, 6)]
```

You can use `zip` a little bit like a matrix transpose in math.  Anyway, for your situation, we can do:

```
for x in zip(*tuplelist):
    for y in x[1:]:
        print (x[0], 'has_val', y)
```

Gives:

```
('a', 'has_val', 6)
('a', 'has_val', 0)
('b', 'has_val', 3)
('b', 'has_val', 4)
('c', 'has_val', 9)
('c', 'has_val', 5)
('d', 'has_val', 11)
('d', 'has_val', 6)
```

You can do this in a giant one-liner, too:

```
>>> [(x[0], 'has_val', y) for x in zip(*tuplelist) for y in x[1:]]
[('a', 'has_val', 6),
 ('a', 'has_val', 0),
 ('b', 'has_val', 3),
 ('b', 'has_val', 4),
 ('c', 'has_val', 9),
 ('c', 'has_val', 5),
 ('d', 'has_val', 11),
 ('d', 'has_val', 6)]
```

Comment: if i want to do this only for 'd' and not for a,b or c, then how do i do it.

Comment: If you know that 'd' is in the fourth position, you can just pick it out from the `zip`: `zip(*tuplelist)[3]` gives `('d', 11, 6)`.

Comment: If you don't know the position of 'd', you can filter: `[(x[0], 'has_val', y) for x in zip(*tuplelist) for y in x[1:] if x[0] == 'd']` gives you just `[('d', 'has_val', 11), ('d', 'has_val', 6)]`.

Answer (score 2):

zip() can work for your problem

```
tuplelist = [('a','b', 'c', 'd'), (6, 3, 9, 11), (0, 4, 5, 6)]

tuplelist_withposition=zip(tuplelist[0],tuplelist[1],tuplelist[2])

s = 'has_val'
for i in tuplelist_withposition:
     rel = (i[0],s,i[1])
     print rel
     rel=(i[0],s,i[2])
     print rel
```

output:

```
('a', 'has_val', 6)
('a', 'has_val', 0)
('b', 'has_val', 3)
('b', 'has_val', 4)
('c', 'has_val', 9)
('c', 'has_val', 5)
('d', 'has_val', 11)
('d', 'has_val', 6)
```

Comment: 1. Don't add "try this" as an answer as they do not help explain the OP. 2. Don't use `str` as a variable name as they shadow the builtin function.

Answer (score 1):

Just simpley use tuple and list indices. If you only want one value from one specfic place in a container, don't use a loop, just use indices.

```
res = (tuplelist[0][3],'has_val', tuplelist[1][3])
```

Full program:

```
tuplelist = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (6, 3, 9, 11), (0, 4, 5, 6)]
res = (tuplelist[0][3],'has_val', tuplelist[1][3])

print(res)
```

Explanation:

- `(tuplelist[0][3]`: Begin a tuple by using `(`. from the first tuple in `tuplelist` get the last item in that tuple and insert it in our current tuple.
- `,'has_val',`: add the string 'has_val' to our tuple...
- `tuplelist[1][3])`: for the last element in the current tuple, get the last element in the second tuple in `tuplelist`, and end our tuple with a `)`.